# Java Date Hibernate cut off time

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, time

I have a Date type column in Oracle DB and it contains date and time for sure. But when I'm trying to get data in java application it will return date with bunch of zeros instead of real time.
In code it'll be like:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT table.id, table.date FROM table");
List<Object[]> resultArray = sqlQuery.list();
Date date = (Date)resultArray[1];
```

If it was 26-feb-2010 17:59:16 in DB I'll get 26-feb-2010 00:00:00
How to get it with time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert with Oracle, but you probably need a `DateTime` column type to get a time stamp.

With that you need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` JDBC type.

Comment: In Oracle, the `DATE` datatype contains both date and time information, much like `java.lang.Date`.

Answer (score 11):

As others have already stated, you need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` to get the time.

However, if you use the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` annotation on a Oracle's DATE column, Hibernate will complain and throw schema validation errors. To avoid those, add a `columnDefinition` like this:

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="EVENTTIME", columnDefinition="DATE")
private Date eventTime;
```

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough! This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (Oracle Date type in the database).

The following mapping works for me:

```
<property name="timeStamp" type="java.util.Date">
    <column name="TIME_STAMP"/>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this issue in the past too. To resolve it, change your hibernate mapping from:

```
<property name="timeStamp" type="java.util.Date">
    <column name="TIME_STAMP"/>
</property>
```

to

```
<property name="timeStamp" type="timestamp">
    <column name="TIME_STAMP"/>
</property>
```

You can leave the data type in your Hibernate object as java.util.Date.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it also working fine hibernate 3.3 , use ojdbc6.jar and in annotation change the date to timestamp
like below

```
@Id
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "TDATE", length = 7)
public Date getTdate() {
    return this.tdate;
}

public void setTdate(Date tdate) {
    this.tdate = tdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT table.id as i, table.date as d FROM table")
  .addScalar("i", Hibernate.LONG)  // Or whatever type id is
  .addScalar("d", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. But I hate the fact I should define types for all of the returned parameters there. I have quite a lot of them...

Comment: You could try a custom dialect. The base dialect says "register hibernate types for default use in scalar sqlquery type auto detection" and has Types.DATE matched to Hibernate.DATE - you could subclass it and match Types.DATE to Hibernate.TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have [this problem?](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-Oracle-SQL-DATE-conversion-problem-using-iBATIS-via-Java-JDBC-p21112960.html) Make sure you have the latest JDBC driver, the filename should be ojdbc5.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I was into the same problem recently. Here is my approach...

So in this case define a **for loop** in the QueryImplementation class ,such that it checks the type of all columns of the database table. If the column name is of type DATE then append addScalar("columnName", new Timestamptype()) to the query builder. In this way the Date type Columns will display the TimeStamp in the java application.

Please find the sample code below:

```
 SQLQuery hibernateQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);

        Set<String> columns = columnDataTypes.keySet();
   for (String column : columns) {
       if (columnDataTypes.get(column).equals(SqlType.DATE.name())) {
           hibernateQuery.addScalar(column, new TimestampType());
       } else {
           hibernateQuery.addScalar(column);
       }
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but in my case the solution was to just add @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) to my date-field.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

And another solution we found (when the first one didn't work) was to explicitly tell hibernate the Type:

```
@Type(type = "date")
private Date date;
```