# @Temporal is not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created an entity using `@Temporal` annotation:

```
import java.util.Date;
@Entity
public class TestEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Date endDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "END_DATE", nullable = false)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(final Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

Now in my code I am saving this entity using:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
testEntity.setEndDate(date);

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.save(testEntity);
```

If I run this code on my Tomcat server it is working fine and saving date as `10/31/2017`.

Now if I run the same code on weblogic server the above code is saving the timestamp as well like - `10/31/2017 6:05:18 AM`. Here I do not want the time stamp, I just need to store the date.

I have enabled the logs to see the SQL query generated by hibernate, I do not see what is causing this issue.

Can you please help me what can be the issue in this case?

I am using same hibernate Jars in both the servers and pointing to Oracle database from both servers.

Comment: _Tomcat server it is working fine and saving date as 10/31/2017_ &  _weblogic server the above code is saving the timestamp as well like - 10/31/2017 6:05:18 AM_. So these both use the same database engine and `hibernate` version? It should be `hibernate` that generates columns and decides the datatype of those columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343339/java-date-hibernate-cut-off-time#17616733

Comment: @pirho, yes I am using same hibernate Jar files in both the servers and using same Oracle database.

Comment: How do you debug this stuff? `log.info(testEntity.getDate());`? Not checking the db column ?

Comment: @Reimeus, The link you posted is related to `timestamp` issue. I want to save only date not time information

Comment: `log.info(testEntity.getDate());` prints me the date and time value, this is expected because a Date object also holds time information. But hibernate should take care about storing only Date value.

Comment: @user3181365 and that's what was achieved in that answer

Comment: @Reimeus, Can you please help me what change I need to do in my case, because I do not want to use `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` as mentioned in the link you posted

Comment: Ok but just confirm what is the data type in db and what you see there? if it is date there cannot be time, right?

Comment: @pirho, In my Oracle database the data type for my column is `DATE`. But even in the case of Timestamp columns also the data type is `DATE`.

Comment: Paste the whole code snippet how you test this. From the persist to log after persit  just as you do it, if the provided answer is not what helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) with Oracle 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232260/temporaltemporaltype-date-with-oracle-12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the time part zero, set *all* fields:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // Now
calendar.set(2017, Calendar.OCTOBER, 31, 0, 0, 0); // y M d H m s
```

Or maybe better, call `calendar.clear();` to clear all fields.

Also in the database ensure it is not a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP but a **DATE**.

By the way: java.sql.Date (not java.util.Date here) zeroes the time part.

---

And then there are the new java 8 date time classes, which are worth the large effort.

Comment: If I use java.sql.Date then I am getting this exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property`

Comment: Yes, java.sql.Date has lost its usefulness for hibernate. Also the new java 8 time classes require a current hibernate, or some conversion. One might try LocalDate too. But I guess it is the database column type.

Comment: @user3181365 Is it Oracle 12? Then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232260/temporaltemporaltype-date-with-oracle-12)

Comment: @pirho that is big news

Comment: @JoopEggen So your comment is not sarcasm and it was the issue ?

Comment: @pirho sorry I did not find the right formulation, not a native speaker myself. Wanted to express that your comment is worth reading. Maybe the oracle changed together with the Java EE server. Gave +1. I am not the OP however

Comment: @user3181365 _pointing to Oracle database from both servers._ To the same Oracle server or perhaps two different instances and versions?

Comment: @pirho, It is same Oracle database not separate instances. My weblogic server is down for maintenance, I am waiting for it to come up so I can test it.

Comment: @user3181365 Ok, please let us know then and tell the Oracle version also. It might be also the jdbc driver version also. It might be different between Tomcat/Weblogic.

Comment: @pirho, My Oracle DB is `Oracle Database 12c - 12.1.0.2.0`